# Open sourcing an XCode project with push notification capabilities turned on?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to distribute an iOS app as open source. It includes push notification capabilities. Normally to allow push, we just need to go to the "capabilities" tab and turn it on, and it would create an entitlements file.

I read through the documentation and it looks like it's not just creating the entitlements file, but also does a lot of other things behind the scenes.

> By enabling app services in Xcode, you set some entitlements in the Xcode project and for an App ID in your developer account. The app services enabled for an App ID serve as a whitelist of the services one or more apps may use. Some app services are enabled by default for an explicit App ID that exactly matches the bundle ID. The Xcode project configuration specifies which services the app actually uses.

Well this is convenient when you're building an app for yourself, but I am trying to open source this, so I wonder how I go about this.

My concern is, if I distribute the project **after** I enable the push capability from XCode, it may have the entitlements file, but will be missing rest of the things that XCode does behind the scenes, so when other people try to use my open source code, they may run into problems.

Am I misunderstood about how this works? If not, what's the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Anyone who wants to compile and install your code will need to modify the project to use their profile and bundle Id. As part of setting this up then can enable the required entitlements. They will also need to generate the digital certificates and install them in their push server. so there is a reasonable level of knowledge required. You can either assume this knowledge or provide step-by-step instructions

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the work required to implement push. I think I need to clarify: I'm assuming the knowledge of setting up push. But the app also contains push related code (such as register for device token, etc.) The problem is, many times people may want to use it without going through all the push hassle. (The app works fine without the push). I kept the push feature off by default for these people, but the problem is when they submit the app they get the warning that they have push related code but not the entitlement. I just want to avoid this specific problem. Do you know how?